# Center SVG icon inside its container

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I center the SVG inside its container: (note that it's positioned at the left side of the container)

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<svg class="record" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve" style="fill: rgb(123, 55, 32);" width="1000" height="1000"><rect id="backgroundrect" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="none" stroke="none"/><path d="M1244.68 306.4L686.8 135c-30.4-9.34-63.2-9.34-93.58 0L35.32 306.4c-47.08 14.46-47.08 76.72 0 91.18l97.26 29.88c-21.34 26.38-34.46 58.56-35.76 93.8C77.56 532.3 64 552.22 64 576c0 21.56 11.36 39.7 27.72 51.3L40.66 857.06C36.22 877.04 51.42 896 71.88 896h112.22c20.48 0 35.68-18.96 31.24-38.94L164.28 627.3C180.64 615.7 192 597.56 192 576c0-23.14-12.94-42.5-31.32-53.74 1.52-30.04 16.88-56.6 41.38-73.44L593.2 569c18.12 5.56 52.88 12.5 93.58 0l557.9-171.4c47.1-14.48 47.1-76.72 0-91.2zM705.58 630.18c-57.06 17.52-105.68 7.84-131.18 0l-290.04-89.1L256 768c0 70.7 171.92 128 384 128s384-57.3 384-128l-28.36-226.94-290.06 89.12z"  /></svg>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to horizontally center an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand it looks like you need a proper `viewbox` and not `height/width`

```
viewbox="0 0 1280 1000"
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<svg class="record" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" enable-background="new 0 0 1200 1000" xml:space="preserve" style="fill: rgb(123, 55, 32);" viewbox="0 0 1280 1000"><rect id="backgroundrect" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="none" stroke="none"/><path d="M1244.68 306.4L686.8 135c-30.4-9.34-63.2-9.34-93.58 0L35.32 306.4c-47.08 14.46-47.08 76.72 0 91.18l97.26 29.88c-21.34 26.38-34.46 58.56-35.76 93.8C77.56 532.3 64 552.22 64 576c0 21.56 11.36 39.7 27.72 51.3L40.66 857.06C36.22 877.04 51.42 896 71.88 896h112.22c20.48 0 35.68-18.96 31.24-38.94L164.28 627.3C180.64 615.7 192 597.56 192 576c0-23.14-12.94-42.5-31.32-53.74 1.52-30.04 16.88-56.6 41.38-73.44L593.2 569c18.12 5.56 52.88 12.5 93.58 0l557.9-171.4c47.1-14.48 47.1-76.72 0-91.2zM705.58 630.18c-57.06 17.52-105.68 7.84-131.18 0l-290.04-89.1L256 768c0 70.7 171.92 128 384 128s384-57.3 384-128l-28.36-226.94-290.06 89.12z"  /></svg>
```